# Creating templates in C++ to handle pointers to objects and primitive types

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, generic-collections

Say I had a template like `template<typename T> class my_data_structure`. I would like the template to be able to handle the primitive types e.g. `int` and objects, as well as pointer variable (e.g. `Vertex*`).

The operations can be:

1. Direct comparisons on integers or objects e.g. using `>`,
2. `object->compare(another_object)` for pointer variables.

Can this be done without having to write two different data structures? I'm sorry I cannot post more code, but this is part of a school project, and I would rather not be accused of plagiarism.

Comment: You can add an extra template parameter that tells it how to compare it? Take a look at `std::map` with a custom comparator.

Comment: @NeilKirk, i was thinking about doing something similar, passing a static function, but I'll take a look into this too.

Comment: @Gernot1976 I did not realize that you could do this! I'll definitely try this once my finals are over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization):

Primary template:

```
template<typename T>
struct  Foo
{
    bool operator ==( T otherData )
    {
        return m_data == otherData;
    }
    T m_data;
};
```

Partial template specialization for `T*`

```
template<class T>
struct Foo<T*>
{
    bool operator ==( const T &otherObj )
    {
        return m_obj->compare( otherObj );
    }
    T* m_obj;
};
```

Comment: is the compiler smart enough that I don't need to the specialization for int? or would i have to write a specialization for int, long, double, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You need to do partial specialization to handle between pointer and non pointer types. To handle all integral types you can use `std::enable_if` along `std::is_arithmetic` .

```
//non pointer type definition
template<typename T> class my_data_structure 
{

  bool operator(std::enable_if<not std::is_arithmetic<T>::value> other)
  {
    // do your bidding here for non arithmetic objects
  }

  bool operator(std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value> other)
  {
    // do your bidding here for ints/floats etc
  }
};

//pointer type specilization ( call object->compare(another_object) as needed

template<typename T> class my_data_structure<T*> 
{
   //... put the actual comparator here
};
```